# Does the MySQL prepare syntax not support the update statement?

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I used the DBeaver to connect MySql.

```
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO mp.test2
(id, code, age, name)
VALUES('abc', 'cc', 0, 'mike');
```

I create a temp script in DBeaver

and try to execute the sql script :

```
PREPARE stmt from 'update test2 set age = 3';
EXECUTE stmt ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I get error:  Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE

I want to know what's wrong with this sql. what's the correct sql to update data by using Prepare?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. https://dbfiddle.uk/RPsGoCC0

Comment: What app language/tool are you using? Add that tag to the question. Please show exactly how you're executing it.

Comment: If I  save and import the sql script , DBeaver is able to execute correctly.